# how to play wav file in all browser with django?

Tags: html, django, templates, audio

I need to play wav file with django. I try audio tag It worked fine with chrome but I can't use It with firefox. I create an html file in apache and It worked with firefox. but I don't know what is the problem with nginx and django. It is my template:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="{% static 'golnar.wav' %}" type="audio/wav">

  <embed height="50" width="100" src="{% static 'golnar.wav' %}">
</audio>
```

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your wav file within { STATIC_ROOT }/your_app/static/ (given that STATIC_URL = '/static/' ). Then in the template, you will be able to output its url using {% static 'your_app/golnar.wav' %}.

This is clearly explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files .

Have fun!

Comment: I have not any problem with output of this url {% static 'your_app/golnar.wav' %}. the problem is firefox dosen't play wave!

Comment: So maybe the problem is in your html5 structure. Does it work on other browsers? Try inserting <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p> after the <embed> tag. see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FUsing_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: It worked fine with chrome ! and about support I don't think so because when I put an html file with this tag in apache It worked fine with firefox too!

Comment: Add the <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p> and let us know. Double checking is not bad.

Comment: I add It in the audio tag and the firefox dosen't show that too!

Comment: <audio controls>
  <source src="{% static 'golnar.wav' %}" type="audio/wav">

  <embed height="50" width="100" src="{% static 'golnar.wav' %}">
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

Comment: What does your {% static 'golnar.wav' %} render?

Comment: I am not an expert on html5 media controls, but I can't see anywhere in the mozilla specs the <embed> tag. Instead, you can specify the height and with directly on the <audio> tag.

Comment: what do you mean? in chrome It render a simple player and I can play golnar.wav .

Comment: Of course, but firefox and chrome do not use the same rendering engine. Show the rendered html.

Comment: It is render result in firefox from page source if you mean that:<audio controls>
  <source src="/static/golnar.wav" type="audio/wav">

  <embed height="50" width="100" src="/static/golnar.wav">
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

Comment: You're pointing twice to your wav file. Remove the <embed> tag and try again. Maybe chrome accepts it, but it looks pretty weird to me. Once again, you can specify the width and heigth in <audio controls>

Comment: It wasn't my idea I see that in w3schools.com as solution of this problem with firefox. I try without that, but It dosen't change anything, you mean Its because of hight and width?

Comment: Stick to the documentation... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FUsing_HTML5_audio_and_video I find it quite clean and clear. The person writing that in w3schools may have been using an older version of firefox. Anyhow, it looks to me that this is not a django issue but html5 (I would change the tags or start a new question).

Comment: And move the hight and width to the <audio controls> tag as you can see in the document from mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FUsing_HTML5_audio_and_video